# Handling exceptions thrown by pure code with `try`

Tags: haskell, exception

I am playing with exceptions in haskell and stumbled upon one thing I can't understand yet.

In GHCi I do:

```
Prelude Control.Exception> let thrower = (read "A") :: Int
Prelude Control.Exception> :{
Prelude Control.Exception| let main = do
Prelude Control.Exception|     x <- (try $ return thrower) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
Prelude Control.Exception|     print x
Prelude Control.Exception| :}
Prelude Control.Exception> main
```

This defines `thrower`, my test expression that will fail with exception.

Then I define `main` that wraps that expression into `try` (wrapping it into `IO` first, since `try` accepts `IO`) and then unwraps it from `IO` (produced by `try`) and `print`s it.

Everything looks great so far - evaluating `main` in repl gives back exception wrapped into Either:

```
Right *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

However, if I try to compile and execute same code as an app:

```
module Main where

import Control.Exception

thrower = (read "A") :: Int

main = do
    x <- (try $ return thrower) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
    print x
```

... it gets crashed with exception:

```
haskelltest.exe: Prelude.read: no parse
```

It seems like exception slipped past `try`.

What am I missing here and what is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, basically ([as Sebastian Redl pointed out earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31231587/745903)) this is a strictness issue. `return thrower` does not in any way evaluate `thrower`, so `try` *succeeds*. Only when the content of the `Either SomeException Int` is printed, namely `Right thrower`, does `read` actually try to parse `"A"`, and fails... but at this point, the `try` is already over.

The way to prevent this is to [inject the parse result *strictly*](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) into the `IO` monad, with

```
main = do
    x <- try $ evaluate thrower :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
    print x
```

Why the `try` fails with your code in GHCi I don't know; I daresay it shouldn't. <sub>Aha: [as Reid noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232517/745903), *it doesn't fail actually*!</sub>

Arguably, this is an example for why exceptions should generally be avoided in Haskell. [Use a suitable monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#t:MonadError) to make it explicit what errors might occur, and to get reliable evaluation of the error-checking.

Comment: As a side note for anyone who are having similar situation, in my actual app it was not enough to `evaluate` expression to WHNF, and I had to also use `force` (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/latest/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:force)

Comment: @EugenyLoy: then again, as I said, you probably shouldn't be using exceptions at all. With a proper error monad the whole issue doesn't arise in the first place, and the result is evaluate exactly as deeply as needed to be sure there's no error.

Answer (score 7):

Part of what you're missing is that when you ran your code in ghci, `try` also did not catch the error raised by `read "A" :: Int`. Weren't you expecting a `Left <something>` result? See leftaroundabout's answer for why that is.

The difference between ghci and ghc here is probably due to output buffering: output to stdout (like `"Right "` here) is unbuffered in ghci, but line buffered by default in a compiled program.

Comment: Very good point. I did not notice the `Right`, and thought it was a `Left`.

Comment: Neither did I, well spotted.